# Having trouble creating a new folder on user input Visual Studio 2010 C#

Tags: c#, input, directory

Essentially I have a button and a text box and when the user inputs text and hits the button i want it to create anew folder in a selected destination, ive got my code currently and cant figure out why it wont work

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists("C:\\Users\\Ben\\Documents\\CreateDirectoryTest" + Searchbox.Text)) 
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\Users\\Ben\\Documents\\CreateDirectoryTest" + Searchbox.Text); 
    }

}
```

am i missing something? help would be really appreciated

Comment: Please specify what doesn't work.

Comment: you may missed \\ after `CreateDirectoryTest`

Comment: i get no errors but when the user has entered a Name e.g. John and hits the button it should then create the folder John in the directory C:\\Users\\Ben\\Documents\\CreateDirectoryTest

Comment: Assuming the SearchBox.Text is containing the name of a directory, you may have missed the \\ after CreateDirectoryTest as @Bolu specified.

Comment: Tip: Use [verbatim string literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx?ppud=4) when writing paths, e.g. `@"C:\Users\Ben\Documents"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't concatenate file system path's manually. Use the methods of `System.IO`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    const string path = "C:\\Users\\Ben\\Documents\\CreateDirectoryTest\\";

    var directory = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, Searchbox.Text);

    if (!Directory.Exists(directory)) 
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(directory); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're trying to check for a subdirectory of `CreateDirectoryTest` and create a directory inside of it if not. The way you're concatenating the string, if `Searchbox.text` is "TheFolder" for example, your string would end up looking like this:

> C:\Users\Ben\Documents\CreateDirectoryTestTheFolder

You can either add a `\\`

```
if (!Directory.Exists("C:\\Users\\Ben\\Documents\\CreateDirectoryTest\\" + Searchbox.Text)) 
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\Users\\Ben\\Documents\\CreateDirectoryTest\\" + Searchbox.Text); 
}
```

Or just use [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string path = System.IO.Path.Combine("C:\\Users\\Ben\\Documents\\CreateDirectoryTest", Searchbox.Text);
if (!Directory.Exists(path)) 
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path); 
}
```

Comment: One more thing if i want to add in set folders after that e.g. invoices, plans with set names after the customer folder is created how would go about doing that

Comment: @BenAllington The same exact way you created the other folder? Not sure quite what you mean.